# Changing time zone on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, date-time

For various reasons my Linux box is running only at runlevel 3. I need to change the timezone of the box. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What do time zone and runlevel have to do with each other?

Comment: runlevel 3 means there is no X.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian & Ubuntu systems the proper way to do this is:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# cd /etc
# mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.old
# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London localtime
```

Zoneinfo directory structure may vary for some distros.

More info [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Timezone-in-Linux) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-change-setup-timezone-tz-variable/#comments).